# How can I make true-false on every click in Python?

Tags: python, button, click, mouse, onrender

I'm trying to improve myself on a project in Python, but I'm stuck somewhere. The problem is; I want the global variable I defined to change to true-false every time I left click with the mouse. This way, I will be able to make a proper selection in my Python window. Right now it selects every row I click on. When I select the second row, I want the first row to be deselected.

init:

```
    def __Initialize(self):
        self.isSelected = False
```

Mouse button:

```
   def OnMouseLeftButtonDown(self):
        self.isSelected = not self.isSelected
```

OnRender(It works constantly):

```
    def OnRender(self):
        x, y = self.GetGlobalPosition()
        (widht, height) = self.simulate_page_size
        y_add = self.simulate_page_y
        
        if self.ismyownItem is True:
            grp.SetColor(grp.GenerateColor((153.0/255.0), (204.0/255.0), (255.0/255.0), 0.1))
            grp.RenderBar(x, y + y_add, widht, height)
        elif item_state != 0:
            grp.SetColor(grp.GenerateColor((51.0/255.0), (102.0/255.0), (0.0/255.0), 0.1))
            if item_state != 1:
                grp.SetColor(grp.GenerateColor((255.0/255.0), (128.0/255.0), (0.0/255.0), 0.1))
            grp.RenderBar(x, y + y_add, widht, height)
        elif self.IsIn() or self.message_button.IsIn() or self.money_image.IsIn() or self.icon_image.IsIn() or self.slot_base_image.IsIn():
            grp.SetColor(grp.GenerateColor((86.0/255.0), (75.0/255.0), (71.0/255.0), 0.3))
            grp.RenderBar(x, y + y_add, widht, height)
            
            
        elif self.isSelected: ## I ADD THIS LINE!
            grp.SetColor(grp.GenerateColor((255.0/255.0), (255/255.0), (204/255.0), 0.1))
            grp.RenderBar(x, y + y_add, widht, height)
```

Answer (score 0):

idk what module you're using, so this might now work, but you can know the current active button instead of every one on it's own, so for example:

```
selected_button = None
global selected_button
... # other lines of code
   def OnMouseLeftButtonDown(self):
        selected_button = self
```

now, instead of checking for every button, and activating that way, you can just use selected_button